# PHP in_array and String contains

Tags: php, arrays, string, contains

I have any array of data `"example.com/imports", "example.com/var", "example.com/js"` i want to remove all urls which contain this for sitemap.

Some of my url data is like the following

```
"example.com/imports/product.html",
"example.com/imports/product1.html",
"example.com/var/cache/5t46fdgdyg7644gfgfdgr",
"example.com/js/scripts.js"
```

I have this code

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($urls); $i++) {

$url = $urls[$i];

if (in_array($url, $remove_urls)) {
// found remove url
}else{
echo $url;
}
}
```

However this only removes if the url is exact match such as `"example.com/imports"` is there a way to check against start

Comment: what you want to remove?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `in_array($url, $remove_urls)` try to use `strpos`:

```
foreach ($urls as $url) {
  $remove = false;

  // loop $remove_urls and check if $url starts with any of them
  foreach ($remove_urls as $remove_url) {
    if (strpos($url, $remove_url) === 0) {
      $remove = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if ($remove) {
    // remove url
  } else {
    echo $url;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Works great just had change $remove_urls to $remove_url in strpos

Comment: Maybe I'm being an efficiency nerd here, but I would prefer `if( substr($url,0,strlen($remove_url)) === $remove_url)`, because `strpos` will check all positions of the string before failing whereas this only checks the first - the one we're interested in XD

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_grep function like that:

```
$urls = ['imports', 'var', 'js'];
$url_pattern = '/example.com\/(' . implode('|', $urls) . ')\/.*/';
$removed = preg_grep($url_pattern, $remove_urls);
```

[here](http://ideone.com/d128ut) an example.